# Failure to pay Patent maintenance

Tags: patent-infringement

If the patent is "Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee" what happens to the patent? That is, can the idea be produced?

Answer (score 1):

You can use idea of expired application ("Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee") but you have to further check the similar type of innovation before you use it for a product, because there might be other relevant patents.

Further, this patent can possibly be resurrected by the patent owner paying the fees (including surcharge) and petitioning for revival.